# $2$-connected graphs with a line graph containing no hamilton cycle

Tags: graph-theory

Let G be a simple undirected graph.

I found some examples of connected graphs G with line graphs containing
 no hamilton cycle, but none of them was $2$-connected.

- Are there $2$-connected graphs with a line graph containing no hamilton-cycle ?
- If yes, what is the smallest ? (Due to my search, it should have more than
  $7$ vertices)

Comment: Since line graphs tend to have a hamilton-cycle, I wonder if there is a classification of graphs with a line graph without a hamilton cycle.

Comment: Have you checked this paper http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0893965912001036 dealing with a conjecture of Thomassen, stating that every $4$-connected line graph is hamiltonian? Its not really what you're asking for but it may offer some insight.

Comment: I did not read the paper, but I noticed the conjecture.

Comment: Is the line graph of a $2$-connected graph always $2$-connected ?

Comment: Hm.. what is surely true is that if $G$ is $2$-edge connected then $L(G)$ is $2$-connected. This may give a clue for counterexamples.

Comment: A $2$-(vertex)-connected graph is always $2$-edge-connected

Comment: There you go then!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a counterexample on (incidentally) 8 vertices. I guess this can be generalized.[image]

The idea is to only look for $2$-connected non-hamiltonian graphs since the line graph of a hamiltonian graph is always hamiltonian.

A natural question now is whether one can find a different kind of such graphs (not Theta graphs)

Comment: The line graph of this graph is from the type I am particular interested and for which I know no name. I call them "strange graphs". Every vertex is start vertex for some hamiltonian path, but the graph contains no hamilton cycle. The line graphs might help to classify those graphs.

Comment: Did you check that it is the least example ?

Comment: @Peter Yes it is the least example.